# 500 Internal Server Error on Xampp's Virtual Host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, virtualhost

I'm using Xampp and I have a lot of web projects in my computer, so I decided to create a Virtual Host, but I'm getting the following error in the log when I use htaccess rewriterules to make some friendly URLs:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I've tried a lot of things posted here, but nothing worked... Can you guys help me?

My Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost myproject.com:80>
    ServerName myproject.com
    ServerAlias www.myproject.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/www/myproject"
    <Directory "D:/xampp/www/myproject">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^404/$ /404.html [L]
RewriteRule ^404$ /404.html [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are very simple rules, but it should work fine for your case, and it should help you start building some more complex rewrite rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(404|404\/)$ /404.html [L]

# Make sure to avoid loops. 
# Ignore rewrite rules for the files and directories that
# exist (such as index.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much... I'm just starting messing with htaccess and this will help me a lot!